# How to test if a method is called on an object - Rails RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I have two models, Foo and Bar. Foo has a method called ask_bar_to_do_something, which is called after an instance of Foo is saved. This method does not change state of this Foo instance.

I am thinking of making this method to return 1, and create a lambda block that create Foo object and check the return value. Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why not mock the object and expect the method call?

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :ask_bar_to_do_something

  def ask_bar_to_do_something
    #blah blah blah
  end
end
```

If you are using factory to create the object

```
Foo.any_instance.should_receive(:ask_bar_to_do_something)
Factory(:foo)
```

Else

```
foo = Foo.new(:attr1 => 'value1', :attr2 => 'value2')
foo.should_receive(:ask_bar_to_do_something)
foo.save
```

Comment: Is this the `should` syntax? Could anyone share the `expect` syntax if that is available?

Comment: @ianstarz `expect_any_instance_of(Foo).to receive(:ask_bar_do_do_something)`